# Redmine installation error on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, redmine, helicontech, heliconzoo

I am trying to install redmine on windows7 by using the below url :
http://www.helicontech.com/articles/installing-redmine-on-windows-in-production/

But I have encountered with the below error

```
Windows error:

The pipe has been ended. (ERROR CODE: 109)
Internal module error
message: Connection has broken type: ZooException file: ZooApplication.cpp 
line: 885 version: 3.0.97.450
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: This is a problem with Helicon Zoo. Which is not related to redmine. Try ask question about Helicon Zoo here or on forum: http://www.helicontech.com/forum/forum12-Helicon_Zoo.html

Answer (score 0):

Install Redmine from Zoo beta feed http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/feed-beta/
Or make the following changes to gemfile:
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"  to  gem "mysql2", "= 0.3.11" and rename deploy_done.rb to deploy.rb

And run deploy once again.